# How to print dictionary values in a readable format on system console

Tags: python

There are 2 dictionaries created:
delack_node0 and delack_node1. FOR NODE0 and NODE1

Their values are:

```
defaultdict(None, {'FC': 0.0, 'NL': 0.0, 'SSD': 11805529.0})
defaultdict(None, {'FC': 0.0, 'NL': 0.0, 'SSD': 13052326.0})
```

I would like the dictionary values to be printed in the below format, with values shown below FC NL SSD

```
___Average DelAcks for 5  Iterations___
    Node    FC          NL          SSD
    0

    1
```

I used print to try to achieve the above format:

```
print("___Average DelAcks for", no_of_iterations," Iterations___" )
print("\tNode\t\t\t\tFC\t\t\tNL\t\t\tSSD")
```

Comment: You'll have to write code that does this. I don't think there's a simple way to get this exact output. You could have a look at [the Rich library](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich) which provides rich terminal output for Python

Comment: Can you accept one of the answers if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data analysis library like [panda](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to do that.
There are various options to pretty-print a data frame. You might find the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe) question helpful

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very easy. You just have to make a list with the dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

defaultdicts = [
    defaultdict(None, {'FC': 0.0, 'NL': 0.0, 'SSD': 13052326.0}),
    defaultdict(None, {'FC': 0.0, 'NL': 0.0, 'SSD': 11805529.0}),
]

print("___Average DelAcks for {} Iterations___".format(len(defaultdicts)))

print("{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}".format('Node', 'FC', 'NL', 'SSD'))

column = "{:^10}{FC:^10}{NL:^10}{SSD:^10}"

for index, value in enumerate(defaultdicts):
    print(column.format(index, **value))
```

If you are going to do this a lot I would recommend using pandas as @asaf has said. If this is a silly script installing pandas is unnecessary.

Also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993049/how-to-format-a-dict-of-lists-as-a-table) on StackOverflow may help you.

PS: The `str.format` method is very powerful. You should take a look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).